# How to disable "Edit in Browser" only for myself?

Tags: settings, quick-edit

There are a lot of descriptions [how to remove the "Edit in Browser" functionality on a Site Collection base](http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2011/02/02/how-to-turn-off-excel-opening-documents-in-the-browser-with-sharepoint-enterprise/).

Is there a way to only disable it for myself because of my personal preferences? I don't even have rights to modify the Site Collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Long as this is being done by Default SharePoint, it is not possible to do so without doing it for every user within the site collection.